# All Socket.IO rooms on server

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have a basic question on socketio rooms. I know that I can access all rooms by using io.sockets.adapter.rooms. But does this really return all active rooms on the server, or just rooms per node instance?

Answer (score 0):

It returns rooms in the current node instance.

If you're running multiple node instances, then each node instance has its own set of connections/rooms and you would have to separately query each node instance in order to get the combined set of rooms.  Keep in mind that every connection is automatically put in a room of its own too so there will be all those rooms too, not just the rooms that you manually joined a connection to.

If you are using the [redis support](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis) for multiple node instances with socket.io, then you may be able to query the redis store to get information about all servers that are using that shared storage.